# Can't reboot to recovery mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, factory-reset, odin

I have a galaxy grand prime.when i try to reboot into recovery mode with 3 button combo, clock mode dosn't start. it booted normally.how to solve this.

Comment: Either some other combinations. Or if your phone is rooted, type this in Terminal: `su -c reboot recovery`

Comment: phone is not rooted.can i try CMW .is it require root permission

Comment: Here: [How do I enter Recovery mode without keyboard or Home button?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some samsung devices (rather newer, e.g. Galaxy A3), there is no need for root access to reboot into recovery mode.

Enable the Developer options on your device (Settings > About device > pushing several times "Build number") and switch on the USB debugging.

You need to install adb http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378/ and to run the following command:

```
adb shell reboot recovery
```

This should reboot your device into recovery mode without root.